# Forwarding video from one IP range to other on same pc

Tags: windows, networking, routing

My home network has two parts:

```
Internet -- |    router     | ---- | switch | -----|--PC1 192.168.2.1
            | 192.168.2.254 |                      |--PC2 192.168.2.2
                                                   |
                                                   |
                                                   |----| 192.168.2.8    |
                                                        |    PC3         |
                       |     router    |           |----| 192.168.23.101 |
| IP CAM         |-----| 192.168.23.1  |-----------|
| 192.168.23.100 |
```

a normal part (IP range `192.168.2.xxx`) with a switch and some pc's. The second part (IP range `192.168.23.xxx`) contains a pc (**PC3**), router and IP cam.

**PC3** (Windows 7) has two network cards, one for the `2.xxx` and one for the `23.xxx` range. On PC3 I'm running a ftp-server that receives images from the IP cam, and an apache server. So far, so good. Everything is working.

Now I can also tap into the livestream of the camera: `192.168.23.100:800/video.cgi`. I've created a basic webpage on **PC3** containing nothing more then

```
<div class="live"></div>

.live{
     background-image: url:(http://192.168.23:100/video.cgi);
     border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Whem I run this in a browser on **PC3** it shows the live stream as it should. However when I open the page on PC1 or PC2, it does show the red border, but not the streaming video.

Sadly most answers about routing here and on SO go about Linux, this is Windows 7, so I couldn't find an answerto my  question: what do I need to change in the apache config or the Windows configuration so the video stream is also shown outside the second part of the network. (I've turned off the firewall on PC3)

Comment: What equipment is your routers? Is it a router/modem combo from your ISP or you running equipment such as Cisco?

Comment: Can you confirm if the network has been segregated for security concerns? If so, routing is _not_ the solution you're looking for - see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You've separated the networks, so I would expect that there is a good reason for this - e.g: security.

As such, allowing PC3 to route between the networks is not a good option... this completely counters what you've setup.

Instead, you could configure Apache to proxy the camera's live feed page. With this configuration you maintain a strict access control policy (only *this* URL may be accessed via PC3), you maintain your network segregation, and also avoid configuring specific routes.

To do this, look at using the [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) or [`ProxyPassMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch) directives in [`mod_proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html).

---

Note: If `video.cgi` produces anything that makes use of technologies aside from HTTP (e.g: HTML that calls on an RTP stream), then you will have issues with this approach. The fact that you've used the URL directly in the CSS `background-image` would imply to me that this will work fine... (this technique also feels a little hinky)

It is easy to confirm if `video.cgi` does this - if necessary, you will want to look into a Windows equivalent of `iptables` to allow for precise / secure port forwarding between the networks, ideally using [Masquerading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (I cannot help with this - perhaps `netsh` will suffice?).

Comment: Generally, I agree. However, if the stream involves anything other than HTTP (unlikely, but possible), this won’t be enough.

Comment: @DanielB good point thanks - I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

On 192.168.2.254 you need to configure a route to 192.168.23.x and on 192.168.23.1 you need to have a route back to 192.168.2.x so that 192.168.2.x and 192.168.23.100 can communicate with eachother.

Based on your router equipment this is configured differently.

You might also have a good reason to keep the two local networks separated, but if you place IP CAM in the 192.168.2.x (without the second router) network you would not have this issue.

**Next step**

Create VLAN's on your switch (if possible) and remove the second router. This will make the overall network easier to maintain and build out.

[image]

Comment: As others has pointed out and that OP has not included, is that the networks might be separated for security concerns. The first question is, "how do OP make this work?" A second question could be "how do OP seure this?", which could be done through several methods such as a FW, Apache's features / other.

Making your network managable is also security in itself, so you can create the correct rules and policies.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no connection between PC1 or PC2 and the cam.

If you want to connect your two segments you need a router with a link to each segment. You could [turn on IP forwarding](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-to-enable-ip-routing-in-windows-7/8970e722-e947-460d-80d5-fd6ffc850f3f) on PC3 and set up static routes on PC1/PC2 with 192.168.23.0/24 => 192.168.2.8. On the camera, you need to set the default gateway to 192.168.23.101.

Comment: PC1 and PC2 in this situation would not need access to CAM, they access PC3 in the 192.168.2.x network which than should access CAM. The problem is probably that 192.168.2.8 cannot find a route to 192.168.23.x and back

Comment: The HTML page tells the *CLIENT* to fetch the cam stream. The server's just delivering the page.